# Not able to start wordpress local host

Tags: google-chrome, mysql, iis, wordpress

I am a newbie in web developing.
I installed wordpress locally by following instructions given under:Easy 5 Minute WordPress Installation on Windows, on this link :
`http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress`

It included installation of:  Web PI which installs and configures IIS, PHP, MySQL and other things needed.

It worked well initially, but when I shut down my computer and started again, I get the following error in google chrome when I enter the `local host` address.

`Local host` address: 
`localhost:39767/`

Error:

Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to `localhost:39767`

I was unable to find solution to this problem on internet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @moses, he said in the question that IIS was configured.   rockswap, are you sure it configured IIS and not IIS Express?  Can you open IIS Manager and see your Wordpress install?

Comment: @heavyd: It configured both IIS and IIS experss. When I click on IIS express application icon, command prompt window opens up with following in it (see next comment):

Comment: Starting IIS Express...
Failed to register URL "http://localhost:8080/" for site "website1" application "/". Error desciption: Cannot create a file when that file already exists. <x800700b7>
IIS Express is running.
Enter 'Q' to stop IIS Express

Comment: @heayd: I am not able to see my site in iis manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like WebPI installs wordpress as a Microsoft WebMatrix project.  WebMatrix uses IIS Express to run its websites.  IIS Express is shut down when you close WebMatrix, and therefore is closed when you reboot your machine.

In order to run the site after you restart you will need to open the WebMatrix project and make sure the site is started.

Comment: That worked. You are my God. I was trying to figure this out for past 3 hours. Thank you. Sorry I don't have enough reputation to vote up.